# Kendo UI Foreign Key

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, telerik, key

I am new to Kendo UI and I got this problem. I don't understand, what are the basic steps in showing child object information in a column with a foreign key property. I mean, what do I have to do to create a foreign key column. It might be a silly question, but I saw a demo of foreign key on demos pages http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html, still, I didn't quite get how does it work.

Thanks,
Vidmantas

Comment: We need to know what is your problem. I mean, in your code(you have tried something, right?) what doesn't work or what is your doubt.

Comment: Here is a jsbin I did for some other reason, that uses a foreign key.  http://jsbin.com/coreh/1/edit

Comment: Just run a LinQ Query to get the values that you want once you map them to a model you can bind the model to a grid or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Below is the MVC example for foreign key column demo:

Its as simple as it sounds,

For example, lets say you have CoachId field in a table and its the foreign key of the table
Coach that has CoachId and Name columns. Now you wish to present the Coach Name instead of the CoachId in the Grid.

```
columns.ForeignKey(student => student.CoachId,
            (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.Coaches, "CoachId", "Name")
           .Title("Coach");
```

Then from the controller or from Code you have to send all the coach records in Viewbag or Viewdata.

Cheers!!