# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hello I am new to Kendo UI, And I have the same question as [Kendo UI Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934191/kendo-ui-foreign-key)
but, I cannot grasp the point of the answer. About the Foreign Key, can you tell me about step by step of accessing Foreign Key in the Grid. if you provide me with your example, that would be great!

Thank you for your help.. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction) with [Examples available each component wise](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/) in Kendo UI itself. Here is sample about the [Foreign Key](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn) in the Grid.

In this sample they have two tables category and products. By clicking on the "Add new record" you can add the products based on the "Category" wise. Here the "foreign key relationship" is needed, to identify what are the products comes under which category.

Based on this relationship they add and delete the specific products. This is just to categorize the products rather than mixing all the products.

**[Sample:](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn)** *see my commented explanations*.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => // Fetch available categorizes from the table. which will have the relation ship with products table.
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID, // Creating the relationship here 
(System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName")
                .Title("Category").Width(150);
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Width(150);
            columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Pageable()     
        .Scrollable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })    
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ProductID); // Get/set unique id for the product
                model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false); // 1st column editable. since we are going to add product names.
                model.Field(p => p.CategoryID).DefaultValue(1); // Makes default category selection.      
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Read", "Grid"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Update", "Grid"))
            .Create(create => create.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Create", "Grid"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Destroy", "Grid"))
        )
    )
```

hope i have given enough information. :)

Comment: Okay, I got this RJK. thank you. but Can I see the Controller? because I got "Value cannot be null". I think it's because no data in ViewData[categories]. Can you provide me with example. in the documentation, I dunno whether it's different in MVC 5 or the example isn't complete. Thank you for your help..